# Unable to sync app in itunes 10

Tags: iphone, ios5, itunes, synchronization

When I run my code through xcode the application runs fine on my ios 5 device. But when I try to sync my device with itunes. The itunes doesn't seem to sync the device, it even does not show any error.
Has anyone faces this ??
what could be causing this ??

Answer (score 1):

See below image: Make sure "Sync Apps" is checked for your device in iTunes.

[image]